# Make entire equation sans-serif

Tags: math-mode, fonts, errors, align

So, I'm trying to use something like this:

```
\begin{align*}\mathsf{
a & b
  & c
}\end{align*}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting weird errors like this:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.321    \end{align*}
```

If I remove the `\mathsf`, or the `&`s, then it compiles; but with both, it refuses to. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Do you want to switch to sans-serif for just one equation or the whole document?

Comment: Why are you trying to make the symbols sans serif? It might be better to use a sans serif math font instead.

Comment: The answer provided shows a working alternative but to see why you get an error remember that alignment cells form a group so you have essentially  `\begin{align*}\begin{cell}\mathsf{a \end{cell}\begin{cell} b ...`  so get a missing `}` inserted error at the end of the first cell (although tex has already read to the end of the align before it notices.)

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\begin{document}

foo \sansmath
\begin{align*}
    a & b
    & c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could also add `\unsansmath` to demonstrate how to disable it again for the following equations?

Comment: It is not forbidden to read the documentation .... :-)